# Pass Colorbox parameters based on a URL script, doesn't work

Tags: jquery, colorbox

the script given in a FAQ lists the following script for Passing Colorbox parameters based on a URL, but Dreamweaver says there is a script error on this line:

for (i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {

Can anyone see what is wrong?

function getParameters(){
    var
    settingsObject = {},
    hash,
    hashes =  location.search.substring(1).split(/&/),
    i;

```
for (i = 0; i &lt; hashes.length; i++) {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    settingsObject[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}
return settingsObject;
```

}

Comment: Could it be that you have &lt; in the code instead of <

Comment: Oh thanks. That might be the answer. Although I just copied the whole script as it is, so I would have thought the colorbox folk would have noticed it was wrong??

Presumably I should be wrapping the script within the usual tags:

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
XXXXXXXXXX
//--></script>

Comment: It depends on what environment you pasted from and into, sometimes windows gets confused. Yes, it needs to be wrapped in script tags.

Comment: Thanks. That HAS fixed the error problem.

But it still hasn't fixed it actually forwarding to another page within a colorbox which is what I was hoping to do!

Maybe you know how to do it?

The colorbox website says I need to add this script which I have done, then alter the URL like this:
registerSimpleNewsletterThanks.php?open=true&amp;height=500

I cannot add the normal class="colorbox" to the link as it is part of an insert into DB.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that, I have never used colorbox. It would probably be best to create a new question for that, so people will see the new title and try and answer the new question.